# How to pass format in direct route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Rails 5.1 introduced `direct` helper http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/5_1_release_notes.html#direct-resolved-routes

Here is code in routes.rb

`direct (:blog) { 'http://example.com/blog' }`

Now I can do in `rails c`

```
> Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.blog_url
=> "http://example.com/blog"
```

When the format is passed:

```
> Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.blog_url(format: :rss)
=> "http://example.com/blog"
```

Which returns the same URL without format.

What I expect to get:

```
> Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.blog_url(format: :rss)
=> "http://example.com/blog.rss"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

> Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.blog_url(dot: :rss)
>   [image]

Comment: Nope. Have you checked it before posting?

Comment: Hi skrypalyk, i updated my answer. It's working in my Localhost

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working in 5.2.0.beta2. I know 5.1 is specified in the question though.